# Trying to setup Mongodb on Debian

Tags: mongodb, debian

I am trying to setup the database client MongoDB and am running into some problems getting it to startup.

What I have done:

- I downloaded the 2.0 version of mongoDB from http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0.tgz
- I extracted it (`tar xzf`).
- I then ran the command `mkdir /data/db`

Unfortunately when I try to run `mongod` I get `command not found`. Any reason why I might be failing at this part of the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did not scroll all the way down on the download page and took the first linux version that was there. Here is the link that will help you install mongodb from APT it works really well. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Comment: looks like i needed to do an apt-get update and then apt-get install mongodb-gen10

Answer (score 2):

Just untaring an archive doesn't install it.. You have to go to the mongodb directory and run `./bin/mongod` to run the server..

Comment: Hi Ondrej, thanks for your answer, but this is where I am getting the problem. When I type ./bin/mongod I receive the error: -bash: ./bin/mongod: No such file or directory

Comment: You're probably not in the right directory. When you type `pwd`, it should print a path ending with "mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0". If it ends with something else, you have to use `cd` command to navigate to that directory.

I think you should read at least some Bash basics, btw.

Comment: Hi Ondrej, I understand you're trying to help, but everything you've suggested has already been done. Still getting the same error, in the correct directory. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
# echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

To start MongoDB:

```
# /etc/init.d/mongod start
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `debian` package for `mongodb`. so just run `apt-get install mongodb` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to install and configure MongoDB on Debian is from the APT package, check out the official docs for [Ubuntu and Debian packages](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages) for step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Hmm I always try to use the apt-get command to install a package, unfortunately it says that it cannot find mongodb-10gen. saying it couldn't find package mongodb-10gen, maybe I am using the incorrect name. I did add the following to my apt sources.list deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party as an answer has been checked but I generally don't like doing the packages route because I've had bad luck with out of date ones in the past. However, I just hit this issue myself after unzipping and it turned out to be a permissions issue from when I initially did the tar xzf.

When in the bin folder I was getting this:

```
$ mongod
-sh: mongod: not found
```

What I wound up doing was this:

```
sudo chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.0/bin
sudo chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /data/db
cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.0
sudo bin/mongod
```

and VOILA!

```
Wed Oct  5 22:46:59 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3049 port=27017  
dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=MyRackspaceRandomProject
Wed Oct  5 22:46:59 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.0, pdfile version 4.5
```

Hopefully this helps a little more.

Comment: This is what I was looking for prior to finding the package! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If version 2.0 of Mongodb is sufficient, the easiest way to install it on Debian squeeze is by:

```
$ sudo echo "deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-dev mongodb-server
```

It's important (in this case) explicitly to include mongodb's dependency packages as shown above, or you may experience mysterious behavior from the mongodb server—more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552663/odd-results-from-mongoid-using-debian-squeeze-mongodb).