# Odd results from mongoid using Debian squeeze mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, debian

I'm experiencing odd results in data returned from gem, mongoid using mongodb on Debian squeeze. The data is good. How can I stop these consistent failures to return the data correctly?

My mongodb is the latest in Debian squeeze backports and I'm using gem mongoid.

```
$ dpkg-query -l mongodb
mongodb 1:2.0.0-2~bpo60+1
```

I did `$ sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install mongodb` to get the newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing odd problems on Debian squeeze mongodb, it seems that currently the Debian backports metapackage mongodb doesn't require its dependencies (such as mongodb-server) to be from backports, nor to be of the same version. So, installing simply with `$ sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install mongodb` often fails silently.

A Debian mongodb bug report [703580](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=703580) can be seen [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=mongodb).

To avoid this problem, just install all its dependencies from backports explicitly:

```
$ sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-dev mongodb-server
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.0
connecting to: test
> db.serverStatus().version
2.0.0
$ dpkg-query -l 'mongodb*'
||/ Name             Version            Description
+++-================-==================-==============
ii  mongodb          1:2.0.0-2~bpo60+1  object/document-oriented database (metapackage)
ii  mongodb-clients  1:2.0.0-2~bpo60+1  object/document-oriented database (client apps)
ii  mongodb-dev      1:2.0.0-2~bpo60+1  object/document-oriented database (development)
ii  mongodb-server   1:2.0.0-2~bpo60+1  object/document-oriented database (server package)
```